# Difference between ($foo) and (foo $foo) as an arguments

Tags: php, methods, arguments

could someone explain this to me?

What is the difference of these two methods?

```
function some_function($foo)
    {
    }
```

and

```
function some_function(foo $foo)
    {
    }
```

in my case

```
public function validate_something(notice $notice, $tok_id, $captcha) 
{
    if(something === true) {
        $notice->add('info', 'Info message');
    } else {
        $notice->add('error', 'Error message');
    }
}
```

$notice is a object of class notice

```
class notice {

    private $_notice = array();

    public function get_notice(){
        return $this->_notice;
    }

    public function add($type, $message) {
        $this->_notice[$type][] = $message;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [type hinting](http://www.php.net/language.oop5.typehinting)

```
function some_function($foo)
{
}
```

Expects an argument to be passed to some_function when it is called

```
function some_function(bar $foo)
{
}
```

Expects an argument of datatype (class, abstract or interface, or array) bar to be passed to some_function when it is called.... if you pass an argument that isn't of this datatype, you'll get catchable fatal error

**EDIT**

What is the value of type hinting?

- Because your code doesn't then need to use `is_a` or `instance_of` to
  validate arguments.
- Reduces coding for defensive coders.
- Functions/Methods are self-documenting for the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

With this method:

```
function some_function($foo) {
}
```

You're expecting one parameter called internally in your function `$foo`

With this:

```
function some_function(foo $foo) {
}
```

You're expecting one parameter called `$foo` but it must be of type foo (an object of class foo)